# Though as an adverb

Tags: adverbs

We went to high school together. I haven't seen her for years, though.

Here the word though is an adverb, I was just wondering if someone could tell me why it is considered an adverb in this instance and also what it is modifying.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

It's a sentence adverb:
[American Heritage Dictionary "sentence adverb"](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=sentence%20adverb)
"An adverb or adverbial phrase that modifies an entire sentence, especially in establishing the attitude of the speaker or writer, as *thankfully* in
 *Thankfully, there was enough for everyone.*"

Comment: You should add WHAT is means in this context. "1. However; nevertheless: Snow is not predicted; we can expect some rain, though." https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=though

Comment: That was not part of the OP's question; feel free to add a comment or answer yourself, though.